# Stacked Histogram not working in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm playing with Pandas and have the following code:

> tips.hist(stacked=True, column="total_bill", by="time")

The resulting graph looks nice:

[image]

However, it is not stacked! I wanted them both on one plot, stacked on top of each other. I wanted it to look like the one in the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#histograms

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a complete example with some test data. It's impossible to see if your data even contain the multiple sets needed for a stacked histogram. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Shouldn't your column = ["Lunch","Dinner"].. Paste your script please. So we can have a better idea of your data/dictionaries

Comment: I think you don't have `Lunch` and `Dinner` columns but you have a column that has those as values (named time)? For stacked histograms you need seperate columns. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36242524/2285236

Comment: That's right. I'm just playing with the tips dataset built-in seaborn. I have a time column that is either "Lunch" or "Dinner". Is there a Pythonic way to do this? What if I didn't know the number of levels in the `time` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the values in separate columns.

```
tips = pd.read_csv('https://raw.github.com/pydata/pandas/master/pandas/tests/data/tips.csv')
>>> tips[['time', 'tip']].pivot(columns='time').plot(kind='hist', stacked=True)
```

[image]

```
>>> tips[['time', 'tip']].pivot(columns='time').head()
        tip      
time Dinner Lunch
0      1.01   NaN
1      1.66   NaN
2      3.50   NaN
3      3.31   NaN
4      3.61   NaN
```